# E/SQLiteLog: (1) no such table: kids (DatabaseHelper)

Tags: java, android

I have an error message with my app and do not know what to do with the code.

```
package com.own.babyfirstword.database

import android.content.Context
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper
import com.own.babyfirstword.customclasses.Constant
import com.own.babyfirstword.model.ModelVideo
import java.io.File
import java.io.FileOutputStream
import java.io.IOException


class DatabaseHelper(internal var context: Context) : SQLiteOpenHelper(context, Constant.DATABASE_NAME, null, Constant.DATABASE_VERSION) {

    val videoDetails: ArrayList<ModelVideo>
        get() {
            var arrPfVideoDetails = ArrayList<ModelVideo>()
            val db = this.writableDatabase
            val cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM kids WHERE id=" + Constant.VIDEO_CATEGORY_ID, null)
            cursor.moveToFirst()
            while (!cursor.isAfterLast) {
                var modelVideo = ModelVideo()
                var videoDescription = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(Constant.VIDEO))
                modelVideo.videoId = videoDescription.split("#")[0]
                modelVideo.videoTitle = videoDescription.split("#")[1]
                modelVideo.videoThumb = "https://i3.ytimg.com/vi/" + videoDescription.split("#")[0]+"/hqdefault.jpg"
                arrPfVideoDetails.add(modelVideo)
                cursor.moveToNext()
            }
            return arrPfVideoDetails
        }

    override fun onCreate(db: SQLiteDatabase) {
    }

    override fun onUpgrade(db: SQLiteDatabase, oldVersion: Int, newVersion: Int) {
    }

    @Throws(IOException::class)
    fun createDataBase() {
        val databaseExist = checkDataBase()
        if (databaseExist) {
        } else {
            this.writableDatabase
            copyDataBase()
        }
    }

    private fun checkDataBase(): Boolean {
        val databaseFile = File(Constant.DB_PATH + Constant.DATABASE_NAME)
        return databaseFile.exists()
    }

    @Throws(IOException::class)
    private fun copyDataBase() {
        val myInput = context.assets.open("databases/" + Constant.DATABASE_NAME)
        val outFileName = Constant.DB_PATH + Constant.DATABASE_NAME
        val myOutput = FileOutputStream(outFileName)
        val buffer = ByteArray(1024)
        while (myInput.read(buffer) > 0) {
            myOutput.write(buffer)
        }
        myOutput.flush()
        myOutput.close()
        myInput.close()
    }

}
```

This is the Error I am getting.

```
2022-07-06 14:10:50.929 22310-22310/com.own.babyfirstword E/SQLiteLog: (1) no such table: kids
2022-07-06 14:10:50.930 22310-22310/com.own.babyfirstword D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
2022-07-06 14:10:50.955 22310-22310/com.own.babyfirstword E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.own.babyfirstword, PID: 22310
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.own.babyfirstword/com.own.babyfirstword.activity.video.ListVideoActivity}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: kids (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM kids WHERE id=0
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2817)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2895)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1616)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6651)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:824)
     Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: kids (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM kids WHERE id=0
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:890)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:501)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:37)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:46)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1392)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery(SQLiteDatabase.java:1331)
        at com.own.babyfirstword.database.DatabaseHelper.getVideoDetails(DatabaseHelper.kt:19)
        at com.own.babyfirstword.activity.video.ListVideoActivity.setRvVideoListAdapter(ListVideoActivity.java:58)
        at com.own.babyfirstword.activity.video.ListVideoActivity.initDefine(ListVideoActivity.java:47)
        at com.own.babyfirstword.activity.video.ListVideoActivity.onCreate(ListVideoActivity.java:37)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7088)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7079)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1215)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2770)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2895) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1616) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6651) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:824)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to get data from kids table which is not exist so it's error of it.
so first ofall create table called kids then fire select query your error must be solved